# How to search for pointers to functions using grep?

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to grep for lines that contain the below pattern

```
       foo(somethingHere -> somethingThere,...)
```

The below line contains the pattern that I am trying to grep for.

```
       ReconnectAddr(master -> Addrin, Node);
```

I tried using:

```
grep "([A-Za-z]\\->[A-Za-z])"
```

But, it does not show the results that I am looking for.
Can someone help me?

Comment: why do you have ```\\``` in the regexp? That doesn't exist in the strings you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -i -E '\([a-z]+ *-> *[a-z]+\)' filename
```

You need the `+` quantifier to match a sequence of letters rather than just a single letter, and this requires using extended regexp with the `-E` option.

You need to match optional whitespace around the `->` with `*`.

Since `()` have special meaning in ERE, they need to be escaped.